# C# allowing dynamic list of Generic Types

Tags: class, list, generics, types

Is there a way to allow a user class with generics to be specified dynamically? That is, say I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
 public interface IMyObject { }
```

Then I have a class like this:

```
public class MyObject<?> : IMyObject { }
```

I want to be able to use the object something like this:

```
MyObject<object> firstOrder;
MyObject<object, object> secondOrder;
MyObject<object, object, object> thirdOrder;
//And so on...
//MyObject<object, object, object> , ..., object> nthOrder;
```

I know for things like Func<>, Action<> or other delegates, I don't know that I've ever pushed the capacity of what these can do or whether their argument lists can so expansive.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

No, in C# you have to define each permutation separately.  If you look at the examples you cited, `Action<T>` and `Func<T>`, you'll notice that the .NET framework provides a large number of explicit overloads (`Action<T1, T2>`, `Action<T1, T2, T3>`, etc.).  But there's no way to make this open-ended; you have to define each one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have variadic type arguments. It might be cool, but it's not possible with the language as it stands. As for `Func` and `Action`, there are manual declarations for each number of type arguments. It's not something special that .NET just for those delegates.